# MS Build Parameters ( Publish to File System how to put multiple projects in different directories)

Tags: msbuild, tfs-2015, vnext

I am using vnext build and i do not want to create zip folders of the packages. My current MSBuild parameters creates zip folders.

> /p:CreatePackageOnPublish=true /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageLocation="$(build.stagingDirectory)"

--abc.zip
--Packages.zip
....
--test.zip

I am using the below MS build parameters but when i run the build it does create separate folders for individual projects under the same solution. Is there any solution for this ????

> p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:DeleteExistingFiles=True 
>   /p:publishUrl=$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)

Comment: There are two different MSbuild  parameters, which one are you actually using ?

Answer (score 1):

To publish multiple projects in different directories. You could achieve this by setting up **publish profile** for each project. Add publish profile for each project with same name.

Then you could use [File system Publish Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337(v=vs.110).aspx) to Publish the output to different directories for each project.

Call the Publish profile in the Ms-build Argument.

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true;PublishProfile=yourProfileName
```

This will not package the file and create `.zip` folders. For more details such as create publish profile, please refer this tutorial (even it's related to old XAML build)-- [How to Publish multiple Web Projects in one Solution with TFS Build](http://www.johandorper.com/log/publish-multiple-webprojects-on-build)

Answer (score 1):

Using relative path (....\a\WebMVC) in publish profile (the profile file names are the same for these projects, e.g. MyPublish.pubxml), for example:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Debug</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <PrecompileBeforePublish>True</PrecompileBeforePublish>
    <EnableUpdateable>True</EnableUpdateable>
    <DebugSymbols>False</DebugSymbols>
    <WDPMergeOption>DonotMerge</WDPMergeOption>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <publishUrl>..\..\a\WebMVC</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>False</DeleteExistingFiles>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Then the argument: `/p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile="MyPublish"`

You also can add multiple Visual Studio Build tasks for each project, just add additional argument `/t:[projectname]` for each project.